# How to create a table with DraftJS

Tags: draftjs, draft-js-plugins

Is there any way to create a table with DraftJS or any plugins?

A plugin which allows the user to enter custom HTML (with table support) would be sufficient.

As I understand it, a plugin can render as a table but I need to be able to edit the table, e.g. setting the number of columns, entering text into each cell, etc.

It is acceptable if the number of rows/columns needs to be specified at creation time and cannot be edited after, as long as cells can be populated/updated individually.

Comment: yes there is some way.